# Weighted precision & recall - With class weights vs oversampling

Tags: model-evaluation, precision-recall

If weighted precision is calculated as

```
weighted_precision = [(pc1*c1)+(pc2*c2)]/(c1+c2)

where,
pc1 = precision of class 1
c1 = no.of samples in class 1
pc2 - precision of class 2
c2 = no.of samples in class 2
```

How does the above equation change while dealing with class imbalance via

Class Weights

Oversampling

Comment: I am dealing with class imbalance problem, will the weighted precision be different if I use class_weights vs oversampling?

Comment: Have you read this thread [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/237901)?